# Extern reference initialization

Tags: c++, reference

*one.cpp*

```
extern PureVirtualBase &instance;
void foo()
{
    instance.click();
}
```

*two.cpp*

```
Derived instance;
```

Can I initialize reference in other file? I get `conflicting declaration` with that code.

Comment: you can initialize in other file, but you have to use exactly the same type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in cpp file:

```
static Derived instance_object;
PureVirtualBase &instance = instance_object;
```

This ensures that the type of `instance` matches exactly - i.e. `PureVirtual&`

Answer (score 3):

The types for the definition and declaration of instance should match exactly.  It seems like you need getInstance() kind of function for what you are trying to do:

```
Base& getInstance() 
{
    return instance;
}
```